# TypeScript "Function" type vs. declaring a method signature

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm still quite new at TypeScript, so other SO questions and the documentation sometimes leave me just as confused as I started.  I'm going to put this as simply as I can, and if it's a duplicate, please point me to it.

I'm essentially wondering what the difference is between creating a member of type `Function` and simply defining a method signature in a class.  Consider the example below:

```
export abstract class MyBase {
    protected abstract method1();
    protected abstract method2(): void;
    protected abstract method3: Function;
}
```

My understanding is that the difference between 1 and 2 is that 1 has a return type of `any` while 2 has `void` or whatever type is specified there.

I'm not so sure what the difference between 1 and 3 is.  Is there one?

Lastly, I'm wondering, given the relationship between 1 and 2, why is the Function type not allowed to be generic?  In other words, it seems like we could have this (but we can't):

```
protected abstract method4: Function<void>;
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not so sure what the difference between 1 and 3 is.

A big difference:

```
declare function method1(); // () => any
declare const method3: Function; // ALL Functions
```

Based on just the number of parameters:

```
method1(123); // Error 
method3(123); // Okay
```

> Given the relationship between 1 and 2, why is the Function type not allowed to be generic?

Its not the same as C#. The `Function` types names to native JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 1):

## The Differences Between These Methods in a Class

1. **Return type** —— Their return types are different; `method1` & `method3` have a return type of `any`, but `methods2` has a return type of `void`.  You can use `tsc --declaration` output .d.ts and see the declaration file as below:

   ```
   export declare abstract class MyBase {
     protected abstract method1(): any;
     protected abstract method2(): void;
     protected abstract method3: Function;
   }
   ```
2. **Dynamic vs. static method**  —— `method1` & `method2` can be enumerated via `prototype`, but `method3` can't, because it is a property, not a method.  Also, it can never be added in `Superclass.prototype`.  In the Superclass' constructor, assign `method3` using `this.method3=()=>{}` only, so dynamic methods enumerated as `properties` and Subclasses also inherit its dynamic methods in Superclass, but can't be overridden by using `super`.  If you do, the TypeScript compiler will report errors and runtime errors will be thrown if you call it.  Here are the tests to describe that I have said.

> Suggestion: You should declare a method using static techniques, not the dynamic technique used for `method3`.  If you do use the dynamic technique, you can't reuse Superclass methods.

```
    class Superclass {
        method1() {
        }

        method2 = function () {
        };
        method3 = function () {

        };
    }
    class Subclass extends Superclass {
        method1() {
            super.method1();
        }

        method3 = function () {
            super.method3();
        }
    }

    test("methods as property can't be enumerated as prototype", () => {
        expect(Object.keys(Superclass.prototype)).not.toContain('method3');
        expect(Object.keys(new Superclass())).toContain('method3');
    });
       expect(Object.keys(new Superclass())).toContain('method3');

    test("methods as prototype can be enumerated as prototype", () => {
        expect(Object.keys(Superclass.prototype)).toContain('method1');
        expect(Object.keys(new Superclass())).not.toContain('method1');
    });

    test("methods as property can be inherited in subclass", () => {
        let it = new Subclass();
        it.method2();//works fine
    });

    test("methods as property can't be overrided so you can't call `super`", () => {
        let it = new Subclass();
        expect(()=>it.method3()).toThrow();
    });
```